# ordinary function overload template function but ordinary does not overload template class?

Tags: c++, c++14

Why ordinary function with same name as function template is allowed ? However, ordinary class with same name as class template is not allowed.

```
template<typename T>
class A {};

class A {};    //compilation fails when uncommented

template<typename T>
void func();    //No problem compiling

void func();

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Would you make your question more specific? "Why some feature exists and another one doesn't?" can only be answered by "because the Standard says so" or fall into opinion-related discussion.

Comment: but 2 ordinary functions with same parameter types are not allowed but it is possible that one ordinary and one template function with same parameter types(of same name). Why so ?

Comment: The template function would have to be called as `func<int>();`, to make it is different from the non-template.

Comment: @BoPersson With classes you can do the same, i.e., distinguish between `A<int>` and `A`.

Comment: @YSC i dont think it is opinion based. Allowing func and func<int> as different entities but not A and A<int>. There might be reason based on facts.

Comment: This is almost impossible to provide a rationale for a feature not existing. So yes, it makes it opinion-based, sorry.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based but there are likely multiple factors for this, and making an exhaustive list would be infeasible. At first glance: being able to overload templated function has some benefits, I don't see any for class. Class have injected names inside (e.g. `A` is injected in `A<T>`), this would be error-prone if there was a class called `A` declared before `A<T>`: What would `A` means inside the definition of `A<T>` then?

Comment: Thanks Holt. It clarifies my doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Classes can't be overloaded, only functions. If you want to "overload" a class, then use *template specialization*:

```
// The generic class
template<typename T>
class A {};

// Specialization for int
template<>
class A<int> {};

// Specialization for std::string
template<>
class A<std::string> {};

// ...

A<int> my_int_a;  // Uses the A<int> specialization
A<float> my_float_a;  // Uses the generic A<T>
```

Comment: but 2 ordinary functions with same parameter types are not allowed but it is possible that one ordinary and one template function with same parameter types(of same name). Why so ?

Comment: @code707 Being able to overload a function against a templated one has some benefits. What would be a use case for a class?

Comment: @code707 Functions are functions, and not classes. They are different in just about all aspects, and as such doesn't have to follow the same semantic rules.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes they are different..I am curious about reason for this. its not clear to me

Comment: @code707 If you're that curious then perhaps [read a recent draft of the C++ standard itself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4727.pdf)?

Comment: @code707 looks like..if i do not get my answer here..